# ms unit in my stopwatch (js)

Tags: javascript

I created a simple stopwatch in javascript. I need to add the ms unit to it after a second. I managed with each unit, not with ms.

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}

function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: note, if you have 180 seconds it only adds one minute. Same for minutes.Beside that your question is not really clear to me.

Comment: I don't know, how to edit `h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
`

Comment: Your timer is firing not often than 1000ms - you should change it to run more often, e.g. every 100ms or even 50ms. And correspondingly your function `add` must be modified to increase the milliseconds (e.g. +50 or +100)